# Understanding Xcode UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have defined a class named c1 for a prototype cell like follows:

[image]

[image]

I defined the code for c1 like this:

```
 class c1 : UITableViewCell {

    public func configure(indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        self.textLabel?.text = place.name
        self.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(place.timestamp)"
        return self
    }
}
```

Inside the `UITableViewController` following code:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    return cell.configure(indexPath);
}
```

But this works not because obv. the compiler doesn't know about c1: "Value of type '`UITableViewCell`' has no member '`configure`'"

And I don't understand Why: If I specify the classname "c1" in the storyboard, I expected that XCODE instantiate the appear. class automatically for the reusing mechanism.
So the tableView method should return the runtime instantiated "c1" class which is an child of `UITableViewCell` to have access to the "configure" method?

Answer (score 0):

just cast the cell to your specific cell

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as? c1
```

and the job is done

Answer (score 0):

Must cast the type of `UITableview` cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as? c1    // to inherit the method of class c1, need to cast
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell.configure(indexPath);
}
```

Comment: What if I have more than one prototype class, c1, c2, c3... for example?

Comment: why copy and paste my response?

Comment: @frameworker To  use more than one cells create multiple instances, and maybe manage them by using switch case.

Comment: @Alastar Sorry I was typing , I didn't see you answer before i posted it.

Comment: Is there a more smart way without to use switch/case or if/else working on more  than one prototype cell?

Answer (score 0):

Please <kbd>⌥-click</kbd> on `dequeueReusableCell` or read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell)

> `func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

returns the base class `UITableViewCell`

If you declare a custom (sub-)class you have to cast the cell to the subclass. By the way please name the class with a starting capital letter.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! c1
```

And in `configure` you might have to return `Self` or `c1`

```
public func configure(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Self {
    let place = places[indexPath.row]
    self.textLabel?.text = place.name
    self.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(place.timestamp)"
    return self
}
```

And where does `places` come from in the cell? The `configure` method seems to be pointless.

Comment: Don't worry about "Places". What about another custom class? I cannot see a dynamic possibility to use more than one prototype class, c1, c2 or c3 for example.

Comment: You can conditionally cast to multiple cells depending on the index path or the model.

Answer (score 0):

To access the methods of your `UITableViewCell` you will have to cast the cell to that particular `UITableViewCell`

**i.e**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER") as? YOUR_CELL_CLASS
```

In case if you have the multiple `UITableViewCell` so you have to assign then a different identifier so based on that you can identify the particular cell. More or less there should an awareness which display your cell based on your data.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let aCellType = aCellData[indexPath.row].cellType //aCellData is the predefined data
    switch aCellType {

    case c1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER") as? YOUR_CELL_CLASS_C1
        cell.YOUR_METHOD_OF_THIS_CELL()
        return cell

    case c2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER") as? YOUR_CELL_CLASS_C2
        cell.YOUR_METHOD_OF_THIS_CELL()
        return cell

    case c3:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER") as? YOUR_CELL_CLASS_C2
        cell.YOUR_METHOD_OF_THIS_CELL()
        return cell

    default:

        debugPrint("That's all folks")
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: There must be a more smart way without to use switch&case or if&else. I cannot imagine that Swift has no other possibilities for that. And I didn"t understand how the instanciating process works: Xcode knows the class by specifying the classname, but the compiler doesn't know the class name when reaching the code to translate?

Comment: See suppose I have to display the students' info to A cell and teachers info to B cell so when I'm collecting the data to display it into the table I have to arrange a data(can add one param which can feedback which cell I have to use A or B) according to a way so during the execution of  `cellForRowAt` I can identify the cell

Comment: That's not the question. Xcode knows about the class to implement at runtime. Because the dequeReusableCell asks for a specified identifier which in turn has to be implemented by the class which is also specified in the storyboard. So the xcode editor has to accept the cells type according the custom class and shouldn't  throw a compiler issue.